# How to convert timestampt into excel text

Tags: excel

I have a timestamp (1394475248) when I translates using =(((*Column*/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1) and the date format gives the timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ) but I have to store it in a timestamp which looks like this "2014-03-10T23:11:09.000+0100" as all the previous data was in this format and changing would require a great deal of work/time.

Can someone tell what is the timestamp format and how do i convert the number to the exact format? many thanks

W

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I questioned in haste! I know the timestamp is Unix timestamp now and i have converted it into excel date but it doesn't match with the string (text) values of the unix timestamps already stored on the Database, which looks like this "2014-03-10T23:11:09.000+0100" where as i get "2014-03-10 23:11:09.000". Hope it is clear now if not please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TEXT` function to convert to s strng in required format, e.g. with your original timestamp in `A2` use this formula to convert and format

`=TEXT(A2/86400+DATE(1970,1,1),"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.000")&"+0100"`